# Popper.js in angularjs (Version 1.4)

Tags: angularjs, bower, popper.js

I install [popper.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/popper.js/v/1.16.0) using bower in angularjs application which uses 1.4 version of angular.

I am trying to use Popper in one of my angular directive using below code.

```
function onClick() {    
    popup.show();
    new Popper(element, popup, {
        placement: 'bottom'
    });
}
```

It's giving me **Popper is not defined** error which seems because i haven't injected it in my directive.

I tried importing `popper` as dependency than tried `popper.Popper` but it gives me error like **Unknown provider: popperProvider <- popper <- myDirective**

> Is popper.js is compatible with angularjs?

Any help?

Comment: did you imported popper.js onto index.html ?

Comment: I am importing it in index.html, It's In my main `app.js`. But that gives me "Module 'Popper' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it"

Comment: can you add index.html and your app.module . try creating a sample demo to reproduce the issue

Comment: I added `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>` in index.html. Now it seems my code is working. But grunt is complaining that Popper is not defined!